# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'. Installing basemap in ubuntu

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, modulenotfounderror

I have trouble importing the basemap module of mpl_toolkits in python. I've got following error message when I try to run "from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mapdata.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'
```

I have looked relevant Q/A and tried to install all the packages said over. I installed matplotlib, geopandas, rasterio, earthpy,packages using following relevant code but nothing works.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-mpltoolkits.basemap
python3 -m pip install -U matplotlib
sudo apt-get install -y earthpy
sudo apt-get install -y rasterio
sudo apt-get install -y python3-geopandas
```

As I'm new to Python, do anyone suggest me proper code. Thank you